# Meaning of 'when it comes from'

Tags: idioms

I know the meaning of *when it comes to* but not familiar to *when it comes from*. My dictionary says nothing about the *from* idiom.Can *from* be replaced with *to* in the following sentence for the same meaning of the idiom?

> When a man is in training, and taking it seriously, does he pay attention to all praise and criticism and opinion indiscriminately, or only when it comes *from* the one qualified person, the actual doctor or trainer?

If not, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Used that way, "come to" is an **idiom**, that is an expression whose meaning is not immediately obvious from the dictionary meaning of the words. This idiom is used for emphasising how bad a situation is and how shocked or upset you are about it. e.g. "You wonder what is has come to when children are starving in our country".

Not all English phrases are idioms.

"When it comes from" is not an idiom. It is using the words in their ordinary dictionary meanings - "praise that comes from one person" - praise that comes to you from one person. A letter that comes from Japan, sounds that come from your radio, heat that comes from a fire.

[Idiom](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/idiom)

[Come to](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-to)

Comment: If so, why is the subject _it_ but _they_? What come from the one qualified person are not only praise but also criticism and opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The *from* refers to the praise and criticism potentially coming *from* the actual doctor or trainer. I don't think it is a special idom like *when it comes to*.

It has to be "it" instead of "they" because of the following rule:

> If the subject is multiple singular words connected by “or,” “either…or,” or “neither…nor,” then the subject is singular. Use a singular verb.

Source: https://www.jkenkade.com/blog/2018/3/13/weeklypointersmasteringsubjectverb-agreement

Comment: Please refer to the comment above. Thanks.